# When I run the code in matlab, it should run a GUI in the output but I get the output as driverhandle. How to solve this error?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have two files driver.m and driver.fig and when I run driver.m it should run a GUI in the output but I get the output as

```
>> driver

driver =

    DriverHandle: []
```

Comment: `driver` is a Matlab builtin function, and appears to be what you are actually running. Don't use Matlab function names for your own functions.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your function name to something else i.e. `my_driver.m` and `my_driver.fig`. It should solve the problem.